# Enumerate through array fails

Tags: powershell

I'm enumerating through all of the datastores in our VMware environment to get names and used space.

When I run the `foreach` loop, it's both enumerating through the array, and not enumerating through the array.

Here's my script:

```
$list = @()
$row = '' | select Name, UsedSpace
$datastores = Get-Datastore

foreach ($store in $datastores) {
    $row.name = $store.name;
    $row.usedspace = [math]::Round(($store.extensiondata.summary.capacity - $store.extensiondata.summary.freespace)/1gb)
    Write-Host $row; #To Verify that each row is different, and that enumeration is working#
    $list += $row;
}
```

Console Output:

```
@{name=datastore1; usedspace=929}
@{name=datastore2; usedspace=300}
@{name=datastore3; usedspace=400}
```

`$list` variable output:

```
Name        Usedspace
Datastore3  400
Datastore3  400
Datastore3  400
```

So it's enumerating through. getting all the correct data. but for some reason the line `$list += $row` is waiting until the last object in the array, grabs only that data, but knows that there's 3 objects in the array, and populates each index with that objects data.

The only thing I've done to troubleshoot is bounced my PowerShell console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that `$row` is a single object. You created it once, and then you keep changing the values of its properties. When you add it to the array, you're adding a *reference* to it, not a copy. So the values seen will always be those that were most recently set.

Recreate your `$row` on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could create a `PSCustomObject`

```
$list = foreach ($store in Get-Datastore) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name      = $store.name
        UsedSpace = [math]::Round(($store.extensiondata.summary.capacity - 
                                   $store.extensiondata.summary.freespace)/1gb)
    }
}
$list
```

As mentioned in the comments, with:

```
$row = '' | select Name, UsedSpace; $row.GetType()
```

you implicitly also create an (empty) PSCustomObject,
but as this needs to be created in every iteration of the foreach and then (inefficiently) appended to $list by rebuilding the array - directly building the PSCustomObject is IMO more clear / straight forward.

Comment: Ha, he is. Run `$row = '' | select Name, UsedSpace; 
$row.GetType()` 
$mind.Blown

Comment: @MikeFrank yeah I didn't address it in my answer but this (the `select`) is a possible way to create an empty object. I recommend not doing it this way. There's room for more explanation in another answer (or this one if LotPings wants to edit it)